# How to resolved include module Gradle 6.x?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using Gradle 6.6 and have a project include 3 module: app, utils and config; and gradles file

```
-app
-utils
-config
 ---Versions.kt
-build.gradle.kts
-settings.gradle.kts
```

Versions.kt

```
class Versions {
    val kotlin = "1.3.72"
}
```

settings.gradle.kts

```
include("app", "utils", "config")
```

build.gradle.kts

```
buildscript {    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlin(module = "gradle-plugin", version = Versions.kotlin))
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This problem is **Versions.kotlin** in build.gradle.kts file Unresolved reference, although I include **config** module in settings.gradle.kts

If you understand my problem, please help me, thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried with a colon in `include(":app", ":utils", ":config")`?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I tried, but it's not working